# windows batch script to rename file with dash characters

Tags: windows, batch-file

Files come to my Windows Server with names like: AB-Cash-20490101.txt

I am trying to rename them to:  ABC-Cash-20490101.txt

My script is:

```
ren "D:\FileTransfer\incoming\AB Bank\AB-Cash*" ABC-Cash*.txt
```

but the file gets renamed to:  ABC-Cash20490101.txt

so it takes out the second dash. How can I simply insert the extra 'C' character and preserve the name with the -date.txt format?

I should mention that I receive files with names like:

```
AB-Cash-20490101.txt  AB-Transactions-20490101.txt  AB-Holdings-20490101.txt
```

and I have to rename each one with a prefix of ABC-(whatever)-(date).txt

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f tokens=1-3 delims=- %a in ('dir /B') do ren %a-%b-%c %aC-%b-%c
```

Comment: also.. note that the dir command can have specific masks in it too but this was also my first reaction to the question.

Comment: In reality all you would need to do for tokens is `tokens=1*`.  As a best practice you should use quotes around the `FOR` options and use quotes around file names and paths. `for /f "tokens=1* delims=-" %a in ('dir /B *.txt') do ren "%a-%b" "%aC-%b"`. You should also make the user aware that two percent symbols are needed for the `FOR` token variables when being used in a batch file.